# Spark set driver memory config in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm working on Azure databricks. My driver node and worker  node specs are : 14.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU Standard_DS3_v2.

My pyspark notebook fails with Java heap space error. I checked online and one suggestion was to increase driver memory. I'm trying to use following conf parameter in the notebook

```
spark.conf.get("spark.driver.memory")
```

To get driver memory. But my notebook cell fails with error.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.memory
```

Any idea how to check driver memory and change its value?

Comment: I haven't used data bricks environment, but i think you can actually check into spark settings , you should find default heap settings there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the spark config when you setup your cluster on Databricks. When you create a cluster and expand the "Advanced Options"-menu, you can see that there is a "Spark Config" section. In this field you can set the configurations you want.

[image]

For more information you can always check the documentation [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure) of Azure Databricks.

Comment: Thanks! How can I check if the driver memory is set to the desired value or not?

Comment: Go to Clusters -> Select your new cluster -> Click on tab 'Driver Logs' -> check your log4j logs. Normally their should be an entry saying 'INFO SparkContext: Spark configuration:'. Underneath are all your conf settings.

Comment: @RudyVerboven, couldn't find the specific log in Driver logs -> log4j logs. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

This should increase the memory usage of the cluster when hit the limit.
It's the same answer as above, but not as a photo

```
spark.executor.memory 19g
spark.driver.memory 19g
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.